# How can i sum in list generators?

Tags: haskell

I need your help again guys about Haskell. The case is that how can i use list generator to define which numbers are "perfect number" (ei.: perfect number: 6 its divisors = 3,2,1 <- their sum is also 6). I've already figured out how can i write out the divisors: [ m | n<-[1..5], m<-[1..n/2], mod n m == 0  ]. 
But how can i sum the divisors with each and every number and where can i state that to write it out only if the sum is equal with the original number. I wondered that i can use a second list generator in the oroginal one, or something similar, but i dont how does it work in Haskell and what is its syntaxt.

Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: The library function `sum` takes a list of numbers and returns its sum, e.g. `sum [1,4,2] == 7`.

Comment: I tried something like that :  [n | n<-[1..5000], (n == (sum [ m |  m<-[2..n], mod n m == 0  ]))-n ]

But i still dont know how it should to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to solve the atomic problem first, i.e. whether a number is perfect or not.  Then you can try for a list of numbers.  Assuming you have a correct divisors function, you can write

```
perfect :: Int -> Bool
perfect n = n == sum (divisors n)
```

once equipped with this function, you can map it to any range, e.g.

```
map perfect [1..100]
```

which should return True for 6 and 28.

Your divisors function can be written as

```
divisors :: Int -> [Int]
divisors k = [m | m <- [1 .. div k 2], mod k m == 0]
```

Comment: Thank you i got it: [n| n<-[1..5000], 2*n-1 == sum [m| m<-[1..n], mod n m == 0]]